# Express validator v4 sanitizer is not working

Tags: javascript, validation, express, express-validator

I have a question about how sanitizer works in v4. This is what the API document says:

> Any of the validation and sanitization methods listed by validator.js are made available in all validation chains created by express-validator, as long as we're supporting the most up-to-date validator version.
>   If you use any of the sanitizers together with validators, the validated value is the sanitized one.

if I've understood the documentation correctly, you should be able to chain like this:

```
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator/check'),
      {matchedData, sanitize} = require('express-validator/filter')

check("firstName").isAlpha().trim().withMessage("First name must only contain letters.")
```

OR with the `trim()` chained to the sanitization chain like:

```
  check("firstName").isAlpha().withMessage("First name must only contain letters.") 
  sanitize("firstName").trim()
```

However the `trim()` methode doesn't work in neither of the ways above. The only way it works is when the methode is chained to both chains like:

```
check("firstName").isAlpha().trim().withMessage("First name must only contain letters."),
sanitize("firstName").trim()
```

My question: Why does this only works in as shown in the last example? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.